# How to debug the creation of docker container container in Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, containers, virtualbox

I am trying out a basic example of running a container in a vagrant docker host. For this I created

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
#Other instructions
```

The Vagrantfile

```
 Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
   d.build_dir =  "."
   d.has_ssh = true
   d.name = "vagrant-docker-test"
 end
end
```

When I run vagrant up it creates a virtualbox with the docker-host and a docker container with state -preparing. When I try to see all running containers in  the docker host I see none. Is tehre a way to debug if the creation of container failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had difficulties working on Dockerfile with the Vagrant Docker provider. In the end I now use a different approach: I use vagrant to run a Ubuntu VM on which Docker is installed ; and I use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to build and run the containers.

This way I can get a shell in the Ubuntu vm and run `docker build` at will.

[Here's the Vagrantfile](https://github.com/thomasleveil/vagrant-phusion-docker/blob/master/Vagrantfile) I use to get that Docker enabled Ubuntu VM. Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859905/107049) I made earlier which is related to the subject.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the vagrantFile. I am not familiar with docker compose and am now trying to understand th value in my use case, I do not need to run or build images. I need the docker host installed in order to create a swarm cluster of these vms.

Comment: I would use vagrant and shell provisioning for that. It should not be very different from the Vagrantfile I shared

Comment: But the idea of installing docker from the vagrantfile remains the same. I am taking up this idea. HOw does this work out in a multimachine set up? Can I use one vagrantfile to spin up multiple docker enabled vms?

Comment: No idea this is too far from my use cases

Comment: GUess, I will end up in multiple vagrantfiles. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to spawn multiple VM on your development machine, then Vagrant can do that. See http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/. Otherwise for provisioning multiple servers you should take a look at other tools such as Chef, Puppet, Ansible, Salt or Terraform

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80892/discussion-between-user-mda-and-thomasleveil).

Comment: Although this answer is useful in general, imho it doesn't address the original question? 
If not mistaken the is why the Vagrant Docker provider doesn't work! There are many useful use cases to have Docker provider next to VirtualBox and VMWare Fusion..